# Redirect URL to Jenkins build page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have enabled distant build in Jenkins, so that I can trigger a pipeline with an URL and a token.

It works great, but now, after clicking in the URL link, I would like the page to redirect to the job build page so the user is able to see how is building the app.

I could add the directive in the Jenkinsfile, but I don't really know how to do it.

I tried:

```
try {

                    String url = "http://www.twitter.com";
                    URL obj = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
                    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
                    conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

                    String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
                    String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
                    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
                    conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

at the beggining of the pipeline, but it doesn't work.

Any idea?